# Optimización Consulta Base de Datos

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, oracle

Resulta que quería hacer un programa que guarde las temperaturas de la base de datos en un PDF. Cada día se creará un nuevo PDF con las temperaturas de todas las cámaras, pero los datos de la base de datos van a seguir creciendo diariamente. Para poder guardar estos datos primero tengos que consultarlos, por ejemplo:

```
Select temperatura, fecha from tempCam1 where Fecha BETWEEN FechaMinima y FechaActual
```

Mi pregunta es como optimizo la consulta, en plan, hago 10 tablas y cada una con temperaturas o hago una tabla con todas las temperaturas, y le hago a esta una consulta. Una tabla será más lenta por tener más campos... Porque en teoría todas las tablas de temperaturas, deberían de tener el mismo número de registros.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No es el camino correcto, el pensamiento de optimizar una consulta cuando no dispones de las tablas. Lo que tienes que hacer es Normalizar la base de datos. Cuando la tengas al menos en 3ª forma normal, ya puedes pensar en como aplicar las consultas, e indices necesarios para optimizarla. Si la tienes bien diseñada, aunque no tengas las consultas bien realizadas te va a funcionar muy bien, y luego siempre podrás dedicarle tiempo a ir haciendo las cosas bien. Pero si la diseñas mal, luego da igual lo que hagas, tendrás muchos problemas.

[Normalización](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description)

[Normalizar](https://platzi.com/blog/normalizar-una-base-de-datos-y-no-morir-en-el-intento/)

Comment: Si tengo una base de datos en la que quiero almacenar diez temperaturas y la fecha y hora a la que se añaden estas, es mejor que cree diez tablas para almacenar estas temperaturas y fecha y hora o solo una con 10 temperaturas y fecha y hora(la fecha y hora a la que se introducen las temperaturas sería la misma para todas las cámaras)

Comment: Tendrás una tabla de temperaturas con un campo fechahora o fecha y otro hora, eso como mejor te convenga, aunque quizá si las separas, puedas aprovecharte, para lecturas diarias, de la columna fecha. Luego tendrás una tabla cámaras que tendrá x registros y que estará relacionada con temperaturas. Además según el servidor de base de datos que utilices, puedes particionar las tablas para obtener un mejor rendimiento. Pero hablamos de millones de registros. Unos cuantos. Sino no te hace falta hacer nada especial

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha sido de mucha utilidad tu respuesta Javi ;)